# SharePoint Office Web Apps 2013 and F5

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-web-apps

We have a F5 load balancer for Sharepoint farm frontend servers and OWA Server.

On OWA OpenFromUrlWeb is not working. I get 404 page not found.

Same is for every link I generate on OWA. In sharepoint I can normaly see and open files with OWA.

I have also tried everything described here:
[How to test viewing Office documents using the Office Web Apps 2013 viewer](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_web_apps_server_2013_support_blog/2013/12/27/how-to-test-viewing-office-documents-using-the-office-web-apps-2013-viewer/)

In logs I see this:

```
A process serving application pool 'OpenFromUrlWeb' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '23412'. The process exit code was '0xc00000fd'.
```

and:

```
    Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1055.0, time stamp: 0x563c12de
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00000000000132d4
Faulting process id: 0x1c78
Faulting application start time: 0x01d213f7061dd35d
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 453bee6d-7fea-11e6-80da-0050568f010c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

and:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: w3wp.exe
P2: 8.5.9600.16384
P3: 5215df96
P4: clr.dll
P5: 4.6.1055.0
P6: 563c12de
P7: c00000fd
P8: 00000000000132d4
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_w3wp.exe_50915b96714bc364cfcc4b11b31c65c182eaf7f_9e3fd63b_514523f1

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 453bee6d-7fea-11e6-80da-0050568f010c
Report Status: 4100
Hashed bucket:
```

Also when I try to connect Test OWA Server to SP Farm which is not behind F5 Load Balancer, it works.
So I am not sure where is error in this setup.

If you have any ideas on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:
"Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 for Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64 (KB3102467)

Comment: How can an update be a problem?

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis If you install all updates on Windows Server 2012 R2, including .NET 4.6 - you can't install SharePoint 2016. You have to uninstall .NET 4.6 in order to get your install to work. But when you have SharePoint installed - you can update ti .NET 4.6. Maybe this isn't the case (yet) with OWA 2013?

Comment: Yes, you can install OWA 2013 with all updates and it works normally. Only OpenFromUrlWeb is not working. When I uninstalled  .NET 4.6 and restarted everything now is fine. Interesting is that OWA 2013 without SP1 and with  .NET 4.6 is also working fine...?